# PowerPivot : Use Relative address for an Excel Connection

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I am importing data from external excel file into PowerPivot (Using option "From External Sources -> Excel File". When I update data from in PowerPivot, it pulls data correctly from external excel file.

Problem occurs when these two excel files (one having PowerPivot and another with source data) are deployed to another computer. PowerPivot looks for external excel file in the exact Absolute Address from where it was originally added. Is it possible to add excel connection with relative address?

Answer (score 1):

If you edit your existing connection, you can use a relative reference.
The starting point for the path, however, uses the "default local file location" as specified in your Excel settings (typically C:\Users\_username_\Documents).

Comment: This allows me to change Excel address, but new address is again Absolute address.